# Open an Encrypted Folder In Another Mac

Tags: macos, mac, dmg

I encrypted a folder in a MacBook Pro running Big Sur following this article: https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/encrypt-mac-folder/

Am I able to copy this .dmg file to another Mac and open it with the password? Or is this encrypted file now bound to the machine in which it was created? What if the other mac has a different OS (other than Big Sur)?

I apologize if the answer is obvious, I am in the process of getting another Mac and have not been able to test yet. I was also not able to find the answer online.

Comment: Yes, you can copy/move the **.dmg** _file_ to another **Mac** and open it.

Comment: Just to note, the password to an encrypted .dmg file can optionally be stored in the keychain on any Mac where the user has entered the decryption key & therefore can be opened a second time without entering the key again. This also applies to an iCloud synchronised keychain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, an encrypted DMG is not permanently linked to the computer that created it. So you can easily copy it to another Mac and open it there (Finder will prompt you for the password).

BTW... you are not "encrypting a folder", the original folder remains and is still accessible.